# Create attendance for employee when pressing the check in button and set the status when check in on time or late

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem about creating a record for attendance of an employee using DATE() and TIME() with NOW() in laravel. I have the table Attendance with column to store the record into database.

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->date('attendance_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('scan_in_location')->nullable();
        $table->string('scan_out_location')->nullable();
        $table->time('scan_in_time')->nullable();
        $table->time('scan_out_time')->nullable();
        $table->time('work_hour')->nullable();
        $table->time('work_hour_total')->nullable();
        $table->time('lunch_break')->default('01:00:00');
        $table->integer('scan_in_status')->nullable();
        $table->integer('scan_out_status')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
```

When the employee press CHECK IN on mobile, the record to will stored in column (user_id, scan_in_time, scan_in_location, scan_in_status) but when i only do

```
$attendance = new Attendance();

     if ($this->user->attendance()->save($attendance))
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'attendance' => $attendance
        ]);
    else
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Sorry, check in attendance could not be added'
        ], 500);
```

This code runs smooth with the account based on user_id. But when i press Create, i want to stored (user_id, scan_in_location, scan_in_time, scan_in_status) and this code return MariaDB version

```
//declare variable for taking current date - time
        $user_id = request('user_id');

        //check attendance using user_id
        $res = Attendance::select('id')
        ->where('user_id' , '=' , $user_id)
        ->where('attendance_date', '=' , DB::RAW('DATE(NOW())'))
        ->where('user_id' , '!=' , null)
        ->where('scan_in_time', '!=' , null)
        ->where('scan_out_time', '=', null)->get()->count();

        //set status 0 - Absent, 1 - On time, 2 - Late, 3 - very late, 4 - On leave
      $attendance_status = Attendance::where('user_id', '=' , $user_id)
      ->select(DB::RAW("CASE WHEN TIME(NOW()) >= '08:30:00' AND TIME(NOW()) < '09:00:00' THEN '2' WHEN TIME(NOW()) > '09:00:00' THEN '3' ELSE '1'))
      ->value('scan_in_status');

      if($res > 0){
         $res = DB::RAW("UPDATE attendances SET scan_out_time = NOW(),scan_out_location = ? ,work_hour = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, scan_in_time, scan_out_time,lunch_break), work_hour_total = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, scan_in_time, scan_out_time) WHERE `user_id` =  ? AND NOT scan_in_time IS NULL AND scan_out_time IS NULL", [$user_id, $user_id, $scan_out_location]);

         return response()->json(
            array(
               'success' => true,
               'user_id' => $user_id,
               'action' => 'SCAN_OUT',
               'scan_out_location' => $scan_out_location,
               'date' => date('Y/m/d'),
               'time' => date('H:i:s')
           )
        );
     }else{
         $res = DB::RAW("UPDATE attendances SET scan_in_time = NOW(), scan_in_location = ?, scan_in_status = ?
             WHERE attendance_date = DATE(NOW()) AND `user_id` = ?", [$scan_in_location, $scan_in_status, $user_id]);

         return response()->json(
           array(
              'success' => true,
              'user_id' => $user_id,
              'action' => 'SCAN_IN',
              'scan_in_location' => $scan_in_location,
              'date' => date('Y/m/d'),
              'time' => date('H:i:s')
          )
       );
     }
```

Can anyone give me some advises on this check in attendance using real time DATE(NOW()) and TIME(NOW)). Thank you.

Comment: Still have error on MariaDB version

Comment: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from `attendances` where `user_id` is null limit 1' at line 1 (SQL: select CASE WHEN TIME(NOW()) >= '08:30:00' AND TIME(NOW()) < '09:00:00' THEN '2' WHEN TIME(NOW()) > '09:00:00' THEN '3' ELSE '1' from `attendances` where `user_id` is null limit 1)"

Comment: You can have a look at a similar questions asked in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72223329/how-to-update-the-timeout-field-in-the-attendance-table-for-a-given-user-id-log)

Answer (score 0):

First, get the authenticated user and then get his email-id or user id. after that on the check in button clicked get email-id or userid from button click Attendance of user will be created.

```
public function createAttandace(Request $req)
{

    // getting authenticated userid
    $Auth_userid = Auth::user()->userid;

    // current year
    $curr_year = Carbon::now()->format('Y');

    // current month
    $curr_month = Carbon::now()->format('F');

    // current date
    // $curr_date = date('d-m-Y ');
    $curr_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // current day in string
    $curr_day = Carbon::parse($curr_date)->format('l');

    // current time 
    $curr_time = Carbon::now()->timezone('Asia/Kolkata')->format('H:i:s');
    $lastId = DB::table('attandances')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

    $next_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' +1 day'));
    $prev_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' -1 day'));
    $curr_dateymd = date('Y-m-d');
    $office_time = '9:0:0';
    $isData = Attandance::where('userid', $Auth_userid)->where('att_date', $curr_dateymd)->get();
    if ($isData->isEmpty()) {
        $req->validate(
            [
                'email' => 'required|max:25',
            ],
            [
                'email.required' => 'Please enter email id!',
            ]
        );
        if($curr_time <= $office_time)
        {
            $user_attandace = new Attandance;
            $user_attandace->userid = $Auth_userid;
            $user_attandace->email = $req->email;
            $user_attandace->year = $curr_year;
            $user_attandace->month = $curr_month;
            $user_attandace->att_date = $curr_date;
            $user_attandace->att_day = $curr_day;
            // $user_attandace->holiday = '-';
            $user_attandace->in_time = $curr_time;
            $user_attandace->save();

            $success['email'] = $user_attandace->email;
            $success['in_time'] = $user_attandace->in_time;

            $response = [
                'success' => true,
                'status_code' => '201',
                'data' => $success,
                'message' => 'Attandance added successfully!!'
            ];
            // in time email message
            $fName = Auth::user()->first_name;
            $lName = Auth::user()->last_name;
            $fullName = $fName . ' ' . $lName;
            $toMail = $success['email'];
            $mailInTime = $success['in_time'];
            $email = your@mail.com';
            $someOthermail = 'test@gmail.com';

            $details = [
                'subject' => $fullName .' checked-in to the office on ' . $curr_date,
                'title' => 'Congrats, you are on time. Keep it up!',
            ];

            Mail::to($toMail)->bcc($someOthermail)->send(new attMail($details));

            // in time email message
            return response()->json($response, 201);

        }else{
            $user_attandace = new Attandance;
            $user_attandace->userid = $Auth_userid;
            $user_attandace->email = $req->email;
            $user_attandace->year = $curr_year;
            $user_attandace->month = $curr_month;
            $user_attandace->att_date = $curr_date;
            $user_attandace->att_day = $curr_day;
            $user_attandace->att_status = 'Late';
            $user_attandace->is_late = 1;
            $user_attandace->in_time = $curr_time;
            $user_attandace->save();

            $success['email'] = $user_attandace->email;
            $success['in_time'] = $user_attandace->in_time;

            $response = [
                'success' => true,
                'status_code' => '201',
                'data' => $success,
                'message' => 'Attandance added successfully!!',
                'late_message' => "Oops, you are late today. We hope that next time, you make it on time. Please take it on priority."
            ];
            // in time email message
            $fName = Auth::user()->first_name;
            $lName = Auth::user()->last_name;
            $fullName = $fName . ' ' . $lName;
            $toMail = $success['email'];
            $mailInTime = $success['in_time'];
            $email = your@mail.com';
            $someOthermail = 'test@gmail.com';

            $details = [
                'subject' => $fullName .' checked-in to the office on ' . $curr_date,
                'title' => 'Oops, you are late today. We hope that next time, you make it on time. Please take it on priority.',
            ];

            Mail::to($toMail)->bcc($someOthermail)->send(new attMail($details));
            // in time email message
            return response()->json($response, 201);
        }
       
    } elseif ($lastId->in_time != null) {
        // dd();
        $curr_dateymd = date('Y-m-d');
        $curr_time = Carbon::now()->timezone('Asia/Kolkata')->format('H:i:s');
        $in_time = new Carbon($lastId->in_time);
        $out_time = new Carbon($curr_time);
        $difff = $in_time->diff($out_time)->format('%H hr : %I min');
        $success =  DB::table('attandances')->where(['userid' => $Auth_userid])->update(['out_time' => $curr_time]);
        $updateTotalHour = DB::table('attandances')->where(['userid' => $Auth_userid])->where(['att_date' => $curr_dateymd])->update(['total_hours' => $difff]);
        $successData = Attandance::where('userid', $Auth_userid)->where('att_date', $curr_dateymd)->get();


        $response = [
            'success' => true,
            'status_code' => '201',
            'data' => $successData,
            'message' => 'Attandance Punched successfully!!'
        ];

        // Out time email message
        $fName = Auth::user()->first_name;
        $lName = Auth::user()->last_name;
        $email = Auth::user()->email;
        $fullName = $fName . ' '. $lName;
        $toMail = $email;
        $email = your@mail.com';
        $someOthermail = 'test@gmail.com';

        $details = [
            'subject' => $fullName .' checked-out from the office on  ' . $curr_dateymd . $curr_time,
            'title' => $fullName .' checked-out from the office on  ' . $curr_dateymd . $curr_time,
        ];

        Mail::to($toMail)->bcc($someOthermail)->send(new attMail($details));

        // dd("Mail Send Successfully");  
        // Out time email message
        return response()->json($response, 201);
    } else {
        echo 'Nothing';
    }
}
```